# Did Liu Kang really want to kill his mentor to get his marking?

Tags: mortal-kombat

In *Mortal Kombat* (2021), Sonya briefs that when Jax finally took a wanted Brazilian fugitive down the **dragon marking transferred directly
onto his skin**. Later in the movie, Liu Kang describes Cole about his mentor, Lord Raigen:

> Liu Kang: He was a purveyor of rare things. Children. Orphans like me.
> **He had a marking, so I chose to take it from him**.

To get the marking, one has to kill the person who has the marking so that the marking will be transferred
directly onto his skin.

Does Liu Kang really want to kill his mentor to get marking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re confusing two people and events.

Sonya is generally an uninformed neophyte learning about the Mortal Kombat tournament, Earthrealm’s defenders, markings, and arcana for the first time in her life; she’s making observations as she sees them.

At the later time Liu Kang tells Cole about the Earthrealm’s chosen’s marking and unlocking one’s arcana potential, Liu Kang has already obtained this condition: he took his marking from an orphan-trafficker and then killing him, unlocked his arcana. These events occurred prior to the start of the movie.

Liu Kang has no further marking to take from Raiden, nor reason to try to unlock his arcana — because he already is marked and his arcana is already unlocked. Raiden is not the orphan-trafficker Liu Kang was talking about, killed, or *has to kill*.